# How to find the relation of a sequence?

Tags: number-theory

Recently, I found a interesting sequence in a old mathematical textbook

$$
\begin{cases}
n=1 & a_1=1\\
n=3 & a_i=\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{1}{6}\}\\
n=5 & a_i=\{\frac{1}{120},\frac{26}{120},\frac{66}{120},\frac{26}{120},\frac{1}{120}\}\\
n=7 & a_i=\{\frac{1}{5040},\frac{120}{5040},\frac{1191}{5040},\frac{2416}{5040},\frac{1191}{5040},\frac{120}{5040},\frac{1}{5040}\}
\end{cases}
$$

I would like to find the relation between $n$ and corresponding list $a_i$. But I failed when I thought about it for three days. I only discovered that(thanks for Joaquin San's hint)

- the sum of them always equals to $1$.
- $a_i=a_{n-i}\quad i=1,\cdots,\frac{n-1}{2} \quad n\geq 1$
- $a_1=\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: Hint: Look at the denominators and tell me what is $1!,3!,5!,7!$

Comment: A better tag would be _probability-distributions_

Comment: have you tried looking at what the textbook says, or is it a torn page that you caught floating in the wind with just those enigmatic figures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The numerators of each sequence are given by the Eulerian number $E(n,i)$, which is the number of permutations of $\{ 1,...,n \}$ for which exactly $i$ elements are greater than the previous element.

See http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_numbers,_triangle_of#Euler.27s_triangle.